# OEM macbook pro battery is full, but it won't start

Tags: battery, power

I have a mid-2009 MBP with a new OEM battery. It only works on charger, but not on battery. The battery status is 'Replace Now' on both Coconut Battery and menu bar.

This is the second OEM battery in a row that has this problem. The sequence of events (for both batteries):

1. Replace battery and it works, but drains fast (100% to 0% in an hour or so).
2. Battery capacity starts to drop over a few days (100% - 89% - 84%)
3. A week or so on, after leaving it in sleep the mac won't start up on battery. But still works on charger.
4. Battery capacity is 84%, holding 100% charge. Condition is poor, and it's not providing power.

[image]

Does anyone have experience in this? I doubt it's 2 batteries with exactly the same problem, in the same sequence. I have heard it may be the power controller on the motherboard that's failed.

Any advice is welcome. Thanks!